# References on Moishezon spaces in English/French

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for references on the proof (due to B. Moishezon, I guess) that any Moishezon space becomes a projective smooth complex variety after a finite number of blow-ups (called a modification?) His own articles on this that I could find are mainly in Russian, except a few survey papers (in English) without too much proof. I don't read Russian.

Could anyone give some references in English/French? Also, since I didn't read Moishezon's original paper, I don't know the precise statement for this result (e.g. if one can impose some constraints on the subspaces that we blow up). Can someone give the precise statement?

Comment: There is a chapter on modifications in the book "Several complex variables VII: sheaf-theoretical methods in complex analysis" by Grauert and Peternell. they don't give the proofs but refer to the english translation of Moishezon's paper that Georges mentions in his answer.

Comment: Note that Moishezon surfaces are not important since every smooth Moishezon surface is projective: So the higher dimension can be useful . In fact for some singular cases, the projectivity of Moishezon surface is known, for example if $S$ be a normal Moishezon surface with at worst rational singularites then it is projective

Comment: A Moishezon manifold is projective if and only if it is a Kähler manifold or if and only if it has a line bundle whose curvature is semi-positive and positive in at least one point  due to Siu and Demailly

Comment: There is a new projectivity criterion for Moishezon 3-folds $X$ due to  Kollár which says that $X$ is projective if and only if there is no irreducible curve $C⊂X$ homologous to zero and $NE(X)\cap−\overline{NE(X)}=0$, where $NE(X)$ is the cone of effective curves in the vector space of 1-cycles modulo numerical equivalence.

Comment: Any complex Moishezon manifold homeomorphic to $P^n_{\mathbb C}$ is isomorphic to $P^n_{\mathbb C}$.  Any complex analytic global deformation of $P^n_{\mathbb C}$ is isomorphic to $P^n_{\mathbb C}$

Comment: Moishezon manifolds are balanced

Comment: Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. Assume that on a dense
Zariski-open subset of $X$ there exists a complex polarized variation of Hodge structure
whose period map is immersive at one point. Then $X$ is Moishezon. This is due to Griffiths and Schmid result https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889630 . See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01327.pdf

Comment: Let $\pi :X\to Δ$ be a complex analytic family of compact complex manifolds such that the fibre$ X_t=π^{-1}(t)$ is projective for every $t\in Δ^∗=Δ\setminus \{0\}$. Suppose that the Hodge number of central fibre satisfies in $h^{0,1}(X_0)=h^{0,1}(X_t)$ for $t$ close to $0$. Then $ X_0=π^{-1}(0)$ is Moishezon. This result is due to  Dan Popovici https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-013-0449-0 . I think if fibers are Kahler and we have such assumption on Hodge numbers, then central fiber is of Fujiki class $\mathcal C$.

Comment: The main question for research is that under which conditions, the Moieshezon manifold is scheme. ? For some cases it has been solved, but in general it is largely open problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dear Shenghao,

I) I am happy to report that according to Ueno's *Classification of Algebraic Varieties and Compact Complex Spaces*, Springer LNM 439, 1975, Moishezon's papers have been translated into  English : AMS Translation Ser.2, *63* (1967), 51-177.

II) Here is the precise statement you request. Given a Moishezon variety $X$, you can obtain a smooth projective manifold $\tilde X$ from it by a finite succession of blowing-ups and the canonical morphism between their meromorphic function fields 
$\mathcal M (X) \to \mathcal M (\tilde {X})$ is an isomorphism of fields. If  $X$  is smooth, the blow-ups can be taken with smooth centers.

III) And finally two facts you probably already know.

a) A Moishezon manifold is projective algebraic iff it is Kähler.

b) A smooth Moishezon *surface* , i.e. manifold of dimension two, is automatically projective. This is a theorem by Chow and Kodaira ( proved long before Moishezon introduced his general definition ).